# Sort array of strings based off of parent array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, jfreechart

I have an array of months in the correct order:

```
    String[] monthOrder = {"January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
```

and I have a array of months not in the correct order. . .

How can I sorts the array of months not in the correct order to be like the ones in the correct order.

EDIT:

Let me clarify, I am reading in tables off of an SQL server, they will end up being in anyo order and I might not even have all 12 months. I am then graphing a number from the read in tables using JFreeGraph... The X axis labels need to be the amount of months I have in the correct order. Sorry for not califying at first... its late :)

EDIT 2: CODE:

```
  DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        m.setDatabase("Sioux Falls, SD");

int i = 0;
String newMonth = "";
String[] monthOrder = {"January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};

   Set<String> sqlMonths = new HashSet<String>();
while(i < m.getAmountOfDateTables()){

    String date = m.getDateTables(i); //Gets the name of the table off the sql server FORMAT: Month Year
    int index = date.indexOf(" "); //gets the index of the space to separate the month and year
    String year = date.substring(index+1); //gets the year
    int currentYearInt = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR); //gets current year
    String currentYear = String.valueOf(currentYearInt);//converts to string
    System.out.println(year);//test

    //I have a table called current need to ignore it.
    if(date.equalsIgnoreCase("current")){

    }else{

 newMonth = date.substring(0,index); //gets the month
    }



    if(year.equalsIgnoreCase(currentYear) || year.equalsIgnoreCase("current")){ //making sure it doesnt graph anything from past or future years...

    //dataset.addValue(m.getTotalForPersonInMonth(SalesPerson,m.getDateTables(i), Store),"Sales" , m.getDateTables(i)); THIS IS FOR GRAPHING WILL CHANGE WHEN SORTING IS DONE
        if(date.equalsIgnoreCase("Current")){

        }else{
            sqlMonths.add(newMonth); //add to sql months...
        }
        i++;

        //USED WHILE BECUASE FOR LOOP WOULDNT RUN WHILE WAS EASIER ANYWAY.

}else{

}

}

List<String> sortedMonths = new ArrayList<String>(); //your code
System.out.println(sqlMonths +" From sever"); //printing out sqlMonths
for (String month : monthOrder) {
  if (sqlMonths.contains(month))
    sortedMonths.add(month);
}
   System.out.println(sortedMonths +" Sorted");

        return dataset;



    }
```

Sorry for the messyness :S

EDIT 3: Oh my I feel stupid... case was off!! :) THANK YOU SO MUCH havexz!

Comment: what's "the amount of months?"

Comment: can you give an example of what the data structure looks like and what you want the output to look like?

Comment: sorry meant the months...so like "January 2011" then the next one would be Febuary 2011 ect. right now its doing that correctly for how many month tables are on the sql server however they are in the wrong order, therefore my graph is out of order.

Comment: Data: 
 January 2011 - 10
 February 2011 - 5

Output
 JFreeGraph with the x Axis using the data above in the right order.


The issue is when I read the tables off of the server they come in the wrong order so on the graph they are in the wrong order. I need them in the standard order for months.

Comment: check the size of your `sqlMonths.size()`. Also as I said the monts coming from sql should match exactly with ones you have in array. Even case should match.

Comment: I got it. Cases... lol Your amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do...

Create as `HashSet` of the ones you get from SQL server. And then have this logic.

```
String[] monthOrder = { "January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
Set<String> sqlMonths = new HashSet<String>();
// Write your code to load the sqlMonths.
sqlMonths.add("March");
sqlMonths.add("December");
sqlMonths.add("Febuary");
List<String> sortedMonths = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String month : monthOrder) {
  if (sqlMonths.contains(month))
    sortedMonths.add(month);
}
System.out.println(sortedMonths);
```

OUTPUT:

```
[Febuary, March, December]
```

Hope this solves your prob.

NOTE: The values of months should be matched exactly, even the case, with `monthOrder`

Comment: trying it out.. Seems like it would work. Will accept the answer if I have success! :)

Comment: Getting an error on sqlMonths.get... It says 
"The method get(String) is undefined for the type Set<String>"

Comment: try the new code and also use `sqlMonts.add()` to add elements

Comment: ok so I did it... when I do a system.out.println of sqlMonths it has added them, but when I do a sop of sortedMonths all i get is []...

Should it be for(String month... or does month need to be something differen...

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a Map in which each of your strings corresponds to its index: `{"January" : 0, "February : 1, ...}`. Then you write a Comparator that takes two strings, looks them both up in the map, and then compares the resulting ints. What you do with Strings that don't appear in the map is a question -- you should probably either throw an exception if you know it shouldn't ever happen, or put all of those miscellaneous strings at the beginning or end of the sorted list (and probably in some deterministic order, like alphabetical).

Comment: Hmm... I haven't ever worked with maps or comparators... seems like that would work. Do you have an example?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to run, so I can't write the code up right now. But Maps are part of the bread and butter of Java -- you should really get a handle on them if you're going to be writing much Java code. Comparator is just an interface that defines whether value A is less than, equal to or greater than value B. You can then use that in various sorting methods, like the ones provided in `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort`.

Answer (score 1):

In java and other languages you can supply your own comparator where you for example could lookup the strings in the correct array and use its index position as a numeric value to determine the order